# What's the number of leaves in AVL tree

Tags: data-structures, trees, binary-trees, search-trees

How can I prove that the number of leaves in a balanced BST is $\Omega (N)$ where $N$ is the number of nodes in the tree?

I tried somehow to prove that an AVL/Fibonacci tree should have $\Omega (N)$ leaves by the Fibonacci sequence and didn't know how to continue!

Could somebody help?

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. In the one place where you don't mention AVL, are you referring to *balanced binary trees in general*? (I don't see how *search* tree makes a difference.) How are *leaf* (node with no descendants?) and *omega N* defined for this question?

Comment: yes any balanced binary search tree it has to contain omega N leaves but am not quite sure about the proof .. i gotta prove it

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.  Also update the title.